# How to I look through an array that exists in a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to loop through array that exists in a dictionary.
What am I doing wrong and how should this work?

```
    public func getItemCount() -> Int{

        var count = 0
        for item in order.object(forKey:"items") as? Array {
            count += 1
            //other instructions
        }
        return count
    }
```

Comment: if you don't what type of `Array` it is, it's better to use `[AnyObject]`. You can check my answer.

Comment: its `as? Array` for loop cannot have optional. Either use `as! Array` with risk of crash or break it down and loop only if array is not nil.

Comment: @Jargen89, did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try breaking it down to two steps.

```
public func getItemCount() -> Int{

    if let thisArray:[AnyObject] = order.object(forKey:"items") as? [AnyObject] {
       for item in thisArray {

       }
    }
}
```

Feel free to suggest edits. Please let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: Yea thanks a lot. I've only started taking on Swift after all my time with Objective-C.